# How do use dojo TextBox attr function to get value?

Tags: dojo

How can i get the value of a Dojo TextBox?

Am doing this;

```javascript
dijit.byId("textName").getValue();
```

But firbug tells me getValue() is deprecated! is use attr('value')!

but i have no clue on how to use attr('value') function

Help

Gath

Comment: I would be nice to accept one of the answers, or leave a comment if none of them can be accepted, explaining why.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Dojo 1.5 you should use the `get` and `set` methods to fetch and set properties. But the `attr` method is still working until Dojo 2.0 is out.

```javascript
var box = dijit.byId('textbox')
box.get('value');
box.set('value', 'new value');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this and its working;

```javascript
var titleEdit = dijit.byId('title');

var myValue = title.attr('displayedValue');
```

worked!

Answer (score 0):

In 1.2, Dijit moved to a common attribute accessor scheme. To use the new style and avoid the warning do this instead:

```javascript
dijit.byId("textName").attr("value");
```

The lead for Dijit wrote up a [good blog post on attr](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/2008/08/19/widget-attr) that might help.

Comment: Post has moved or is no longer available.